# Generic method for database update

Tags: c#

I use following method to update orgnrs in a database:

```
UpdateService service = new  UpdateService()
service.UpdateDocsA(orgnrs);

public void UpdateDocsA(List<string> orgnrs)
{
    using (var context = new Data.InexchangeEntitiesA())
    {
        foreach (string orgnr in orgnrs)
        {
            try
            {
                Data.Customers customer = new Data.Customers();
                customer.CustNo = orgnr.Trim();
                context.Customers.Add(customer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Problem is that I have multiple databases with similar update.

```
service.UpdateDocsA(orgnrs);
service.UpdateDocsB(orgnrs);
service.UpdateDocsC(orgnrs);
service.UpdateDocsC(orgnrs);
```

The only difference is in following line:

```
using (var context = new Data.InexchangeEntitiesA())
using (var context = new Data.InexchangeEntitiesB())
using (var context = new Data.InexchangeEntitiesC())
using (var context = new Data.InexchangeEntitiesD())
```

I want to create a generic update method. Any ideas how can I achieve it? or how to pass `Data.InexchangeEntities` to a method?

Comment: Is this a representation of an inheritance hierarchy in the db?

Comment: Have a look at named/keyed dependency injection.

Comment: do your different entities have a common base-interface you could use in that generic method as constraint?

Comment: Please, everyone, stop writing `catch (Exception ex)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve that. The most obvious to me is extract what is **common** and create multiple methods for that:

```
public void UpdateDocsA(List<string> orgnrs)
{
    using (var context = new Data.InexchangeEntitiesA())
    {
        Perform(context, orgnrs);
    }
}
void Perform(DbContext context, List<string> orgnrs)
{
    foreach (string orgnr in orgnrs)
    {
        try
        {
            Data.Customers customer = new Data.Customers();
            customer.CustNo = orgnr.Trim();
            context.Customers.Add(customer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This will reduce the duplicated code massivly. However it still feels ugly, because you still have four `Update`-methods.

You could also extract what is **uncommon** and inject a paremeter to switch on:

```
public void UpdateDocs(string type, List<string> orgnrs)
{
    using (var context = GetContext(type))
    {
        Perform(context, orgnrs);
    }
}
DbContext GetContext(string type) 
{
    return type == "A" ? new Data.InexchangeEntitiesA() :
           type == "B" ? new Data.InexchangeEntitiesB() :
           type == "C" ? new Data.InexchangeEntitiesC() :
           new Data.InexchangeEntitiesD();
}
```

This does not seem much better, does it? We only have a single method, however it still uses some weird type-switching. Let´s try something more **generic** - assuming all your entities have some common base-interface or -class:

```
public void UpdateDocs<T>(List<string> orgnrs) where T: IMyInterface, new()
{
    using (var context = new T)
    {
        Perform(context, orgnrs);
    }
}
```

Comment: `where T:  IMyInterface, new()`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the method signature for `InexchangeEntitiesA()` and `InexchangeEntitiesB()` etc. is common why not pass that in to your `UpdateDocs` method?

If we assume those methods all return an `IDataContext` object which implements a `Customers()` method;

```
UpdateService service = new  UpdateService()
service.UpdateDocs(Data.InexchangeEntitiesA, orgnrs);
service.UpdateDocs(Data.InexchangeEntitiesB, orgnrs);
service.UpdateDocs(Data.InexchangeEntitiesC, orgnrs);
service.UpdateDocs(Data.InexchangeEntitiesD, orgnrs);

public void UpdateDocs<T>(Func<T> getContext, List<string> orgnrs) where T : IDataContext
{
  using (var context = getContext())
  {
    foreach (string orgnr in orgnrs)
    {
      try
      {
        Data.Customers customer = context.Customers();
        customer.CustNo = orgnr.Trim();
        context.Customers.Add(customer);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

      }
   }
   context.SaveChanges();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or something like this

```
public class Customer { }

public interface ISomeFunkyInterface
{
   DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class DbContextA : DbContext, ISomeFunkyInterface
{
   public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public void UpdateDocs<T>(List<string> orgnrs) 
   where T : DbContext, ISomeFunkyInterface ,new()
{
   using var context = new T();

   foreach (string orgnr in orgnrs)
   {
      context.Customers.Add(...);
   }
   
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
service.UpdateDocs(orgnrs, new Data.InexchangeEntitiesA());
service.UpdateDocs(orgnrs, new Data.InexchangeEntitiesB());
service.UpdateDocs(orgnrs, new Data.InexchangeEntitiesC());
service.UpdateDocs(orgnrs, new Data.InexchangeEntitiesD());
service.UpdateDocs(orgnrs, new Data.InexchangeEntitiesE());

...


    public void UpdateDocs(List<string> orgnrs, YOURCONTEXTTYPE context)
    {
        using (context)
        {
            foreach (string orgnr in orgnrs)
            {
                try
                {
                    Data.Customers customer = new Data.Customers();
                    customer.CustNo = orgnr.Trim();
                    context.Customers.Add(customer);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```